# where we need to set hibernate session to thread local object

Tags: java, hibernate

```
ThreadLocal<Session> tl = new ThreadLocal<Session>();
    tl.set(session);
```

to get the session,

```
  Employee emp = (Employee)((Session)tl.get().get(Employee.class, 1));
```

If our application is web based, the web container creates a separate thread for each request.
If all these requests concurrently using the same single Session object , we should get 
unwanted results in our database operations.
To overcome from above results, it is good practice to set our session to threadLocal object
which does not allows concurrent usage of session.I think, If it is correct the application performance should be very poor.
What is the good approach  in above scenarios.
If I'm in wrong track , in which situations we need to go for ThreadLocal.
I'm new to hibernate, please excuse me if this type questioning is silly.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Core concept of ThreadLocal is, “every thread that accesses a ThreadLocal variable via its get or set method has its own, independently initialized copy of the variable”.

Comment: Are you using spring along with hibernate ?

Comment: Don't do that yourself. Use Hibernate native support for that: `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`. It seems your tutorial on Hibernate is outdated.

Comment: yes @Santosh I'm using Spring along with hibernate

Comment: is SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() produces correct results in multithreaded environments. @JB Nizet

Answer (score 3):

Putting the Hibernate `Session` in `ThreadLocal` is unlikely to achieve the isolation between requests that you want.  Surely you create a new `Session` for each request using a `SessionFactory` backed by a connection pooling implementation of `DataSource`, which means that the local reference to the `Session` is on the stack anyway.  Changing that local reference to a member variable only complicates the code, imho.

Anyhow, ensuring isolation within a single container doesn't address the actual problem - how is data accessed efficiently while maintaining consistency within a multi-threaded environment.

There are two parts to the problem you mention - the first is that a database connection is an expensive resource, the second that you need to ensure some level of data consistency between threads/requests.

The general approach to the resource problem is to use a database connection pool (which I'd guess you're already doing).  As each request is processed, connections are obtained from the pool and returned when finished but importantly the connections in the pool are maintained beyond the lifetime of a request thus avoiding the cost of creating a connection each time it is needed.

The consistency problem is a little trickier and there's no one size fits all [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model#Types).  What you need to be doing is thinking about what level of consistency you need - questions like does it matter if data is read at the same time it's being written, do updates absolutely have to be atomic, etc.

Once you know the answer to these questions there two places you need to look at consistency - in the database and in the code.

With the database you need to look at [database level locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28database%29) and create a scheme suitable for your application by applying that appropriate [isolation levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_level).

With the code, things are a little more complicated.  Data is often loaded and displayed for a period of time before updates are written back - no problem if there's a single user but in a multi-user system it's possible that updates are made based on stale data or multiple updates occur simulatiously.  It may be acceptable to have a policy of last update wins, in which case it's simple, but if not you'll need to be using version numbers or old/new comparisons to ensure integrity at the time the updates are applied.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you have compulsion of using `ThreadLocal`. Using `ThreadLocal` to store session object is definitely is not a good idea, specially when you are using hibernate along with spring.

A typical scheme for using Hibernate with Spring is:

1. Inject the `sessionFactory` in your DAO. I assume that you have `sessionFactory` already configured which is backed by a *pooled datasource*.
2. Now in your DAO class, a session can  be accessed as follows.

   `Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();`

Here is a link to [related article](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight).

Please note that this example is specific to Hiberante 3.x APIs.  This takes care of session creation/closure/thread-safety aspect internally and its neat too.